# Rails: Multiple dropdown menus collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, collection-select

Super Rails n00b here: Currently I have a form with the following code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

and it currently works how I want it to but now I would like to have multiple drop down menus so I can select multiple accounts. I do not want the multiple select to be on the same dropdown.

If I do this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

only the last selection appears in the params. How can I make it so the params would look like this:

```
"journal"=>{"account_ids"=>["1","2","3"]}
```

Can collection.select do this or should I be using something different? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one option `:multiple` :

```
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, 
                        :id, :name, { include_blank: true },
                         { multiple: true } %>
```

Note: [`:multiple`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)- If set to `true` the selection will allow multiple choices.

I wrote a little snippet to test it. My code :

```
<%= form_for @track, url: fetch_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :label, @tracks, :id, :title, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the page :

[image: drodown]

Or, if you really want to duplicate:

```
<% klass = f.object.class.model_name.param_key %>
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, { include_blank: true } , { name: "#{klass}[account_ids][]" } %>
```

Write the above line 3 times.

Comment: Hi Arup, thanks for the response. However, I wanted just to make multiple dropdown menus, not be able to select multiple choices in the same menu.

Comment: @ckg61386 You are doing multiple selection but maximum `3`. That you can handle using `javascript`. There is no point to copy the same dropdown values N times if you want maximum `N` value selections......

Answer (score 1):

If your parameter name ends in "[]", then all inputs with that name will be collated into an array with that name.

So, your select tag (in html) will be like

```
<select name="account_ids[]"><option>...
```

and to make this using the collection_select helper, try

```
<%= f.collection_select :account_ids, @accounts, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {:name => 'account_ids[]'} %>
```

Comment: On second glance, this actually gave it separate params of account_id but I would like it to be in the journal params like: "journal"=>{accounts: ["1","2","3"]}

Comment: Ah then the name should be "journal[accounts][]". Putting a string inside the square brackets makes it a hash structure rather than array. These can be combined in any way you want to make any data structure of nested arrays and hashes.

Comment: And, in your original question you said you wanted params like `:journal => {:account_ids => [1,2,3]}`, (i missed that, sorry), so if you want `account_ids` rather than `accounts` (like you said in your comment) then the name attribute should be `"journal[account_ids][]"`